# Ember component not updating on route change

Tags: ember.js, components

I have a template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="question">
  <form class="uk-form uk-animation-slide-right">
    <legend>{{title}}</legend>
    <fieldset>
      {{response-component type answer=answer}}
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</script>
```

which depends on a helper which takes `type` from my question object and chooses a component based on it:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('response-component', function(type, options) {
  var component = Ember.Handlebars.get(this, type, options) + '-response',
      helper = Ember.Handlebars.resolveHelper(options.data.view.container, component);

  helper.call(this, options);
});
```

Problem is, when the route points to a different question object and `type` changes, the component does not update accordingly. How can I fix/get around this?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're doing here, but if you just use `registerHelper` it doesn't bind the values, whereas `registerBoundHelper` does.  Like I said, I'm not positive what you're doing, so this is a stab in the dark.

Comment: I tried using `registerBoundHelper` but get an error: `You can't use appendChild outside of the rendering process`

Comment: Were you able to find a fix for this?